# Removing Shipping Method for particular products

Tags: shipping-methods

***Magento 1.0.4.1***

I need to remove anything other than ground shipping for any method for a group of products that have a SKU that begins with 'NOTE'

I'm thinking that I could modify the available template below. Any ideas how to get the sku, here?

```
<dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
<dd>
    <ul>
    <?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; 
          foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>           
        <li>
           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
            <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?></li></ul></li></ul>
           <?php else: ?>
                <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
                <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                    (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                <?php endif; ?>
                </label>
           <?php endif ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</dd>
<dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
<dd>
    <ul>
    <?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; 
          foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>           
        <li>
           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
            <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?></li></ul></li></ul>
           <?php else: ?>
                <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
                <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                    (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                <?php endif; ?>
                </label>
           <?php endif ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</dd>
```

Comment: are you using magento 1.0.4? please tell me that is a typo

Comment: No, it is not. We can't upgrade because of the contractor making major mods to core code that are critical to our application. We are looking to replace within the next 6 mos but I need to know how to do this now for our current cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't validate it because i don't have access to such old distribution however I can try to help you.

Take a look at

> **Magento_Shipping_Carrier_Abstract** Model

If you have a method called `proccessAdditionalValidation()` you can override this model and perform the product validation for every *Shipping Methods*.

If some *Shipping Method* it's overriding that method and does not call to `parent::proccessAdditionalValidation()` you should override that method too.

Comment: I don't know how to do what you are talking about.